# LinkTo passes the wrong object

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

### Background

In my application I have `nodes` (generic data), and `services` (a kind of `node`). I can get the data from the backend by requesting to the URLs `.../api/nodes` and `.../api/services`. All `services` are also `nodes`, so those are also returned by requesting the `nodes` (`services` is a subset of `nodes`). The reason why I do this is because in some views / templates I am interested in the specific `services` features, but in other views I am interested in the generic `node` properties.

### The problem

For the services, I have an index controller (table listing of all `services`) and a show controller (detail of a specific `service`). This is the indexRouter:

```
App.ServicesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function () {
        return App.Service.find();
    }
});
```

In the index controller, I am getting the right objects, of type `App.Service` (as seen in dump of the Ember object, in `_reference.type`. I inspect the objects in the console from the index template by doing:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each model}}
        {{log this}}
        <tr class="odd-even">
            <td>{{#linkTo "services.show" this}}{{shortId id}}{{/linkTo}}</td>
            ...
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

But in my show controller, I am receiving other objects. They have "related" data (they have the same `id`), but are new ember objects (in this case of type `App.Node`, as seen in `_reference.type`) I have verified that the route setup is already receiving the wrong objects:

```
App.ServicesShowRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller, node) {
        console.log('ServicesShowRoute.setupController > node -> %o', node);
        controller.set('model', node);
    }
});
```

I fear that ember is getting mixed up by the fact that there are different objects with the same `id`. They correspond to different models and different api endpoints, but they are esentially the same data in the backend, although ember should not be aware of this fact. What confuses me completely is that the index controller has the right data, but the show controller (which gets the data via `linkTo` from the index controller), has the wrong data.

Could this be a problem with `linkTo`. Why is `linkTo` passing a different object to the `ServicesShowRoute.setupController` than the one it is seeing in the `index` template?

What actions could you suggest to further debug this issue? I am currently out of ideas. To make things even more strange, I have other kind of objects (`agents`), which are implemented exactly the same as the `services` are, but they are not showing this strange behaviour.

Comment: as for the `ServicesShowRoute` have you tried removing the route definition completely, since what you are doing in setupcontroller is the default behaviour ember does automatically for you? As stated in the docs *The default setupController hook sets the model property of the associated controller to the route handler's model. If you want to configure a controller other than the controller associated with the route handler, use the controllerFor method*

Comment: one more thing you could do in your `each` loop is to define it more verbose like `{{#each service in model}}` maybe something is getting mixed up by using `this`

Comment: I have removed the ServicesShowRoute completely, but I get the same behaviour. The show template is getting a `Node`, not a `Service`.  As for the `each`, it does not work wiht that syntax (empty rows, it seems `service` is not set to the `model` content)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I finally found it! It was not related to the templates/controllers/models/views. The  problem is that in my routes configuration I was using a generic `:node_id`, and linkTo apparently uses the name of the dynamic segment to select the type of object - even if it is being passed explicitely an object?! Now I have solved it by specifying `:service_id` for the services. So much magic going on! :)

Comment: oh yes using `:service_id` for a service model makes sense instead of `:node_id` didn't think of that.